# How do I further amend this code so that it shows the number of exclamation mark the users want?

Tags: python

My code:

```
sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
    amount=input("Please input the number of '!'(s) that you want to print before stop printing? ")
    for j in sentence:
        if amount='1':
            if j == '!':
                print(j)
                break
            else:
                print(j, end='')
        if amount='2':
```

I tried but I could't think of any way that will work if the amount entered is 2...as I think if I search j=='!' to continue, it will come out the exact same result as when amount==1...

Expected output:

```
Please input the number of '!'(s) that you want to print before stop printing? 3
I am honest!
I do!
I do!
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should simply decrement `amount` each time it *isn't* 1 and `j == '!'`. Eventually, your loop will reach `amount == 1` and your loop will exit as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You were not far. You have just to convert amount to an int, and use it as a counter:

```
sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
amount=input("Please input the number of '!'(s) that you want to print before stop printing? ")
amount = int(amount)
for j in sentence:
    if amount == 0:
        break
    if j == '!':
        amount -= 1
        print(j)
    else:
        print(j, end='')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! But I am wondering if there is a way to do this--> if users entered an amount which is >1, the system can sense the number and print out the corresponding number of the exclamation mark? or it is what you wrote on the above?